# User displayName returns null in Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to add a user's DisplayName upon creating a new user. When I tried to use updateProfile method, it gives below warning

/// Updates a user's profile data.

@Deprecated(
'Will be removed in version 2.0.0. '
'Use updatePhotoURL and updateDisplayName instead.',

How can get around this ??

```
      String email, String password) async {
    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
    await userCredential.user.updateDisplayName('Mohamed Rahuman');
    User user = userCredential.user;
    print(user);
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
  }
```

flutter: User(displayName: null, email: test1@gmail.com, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2021-06-06 10:35:13.689, lastSignInTime: 2021-06-06 10:35:13.689), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: test1@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: test1@gmail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: gghhhhhhhh55555666)

THIS IS FIXED: with firebase_auth 1.3.0 (see the Changelog)

Comment: Try to call `reload()` (https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html) before print statement like this: `await userCredential.user.reload()`

Comment: Hi Simon, I tried your solution, still getting null,

Comment: There was an issue with updating User.updateDisplayName and User.updatePhotoURL, now with firebase_auth 1.3.0 they have fixed that bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved by calling:

```
await user.reload();
user = await _auth.currentUser;
```

this is the full code snippet:

```
UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
User? user = result.user;
if (user != null) {
   //add display name for just created user
   user.updateDisplayName(displayName);
   //get updated user
   await user.reload();
   user = await _auth.currentUser;
   //print final version to console
   print("Registered user:");
   print(user);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in my signup function while updating (updatePhotoURL)
You need to update your user by

```
ourUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
await ourUser!.updatePhotoURL(defaultProfileImage);
await ourUser!.displayName(userName);
```

###### Check how I did it

```
  Future register(
  String email,
  String password,
  String? name,
  String? mob,
  String? description,
  //DateTime? signUPDate,
      ) async {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      UserCredential authResult = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password,);
      ourUser = authResult.user;
      setIsLoading(false);
      //create new doc for the user with his unique uid
      await UserDatabaseServices(uid: ourUser!.uid)
          .addUserData(ourUser!.uid,email,password,name,mob,description,currentTime);
      ourUser = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      await ourUser!.updatePhotoURL(defaultProfileImage);
      notifyListeners();
      return ourUser;
    } on SocketException {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setMessage('No internet');
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setMessage(e.message);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was displayName and photoURL is unable to be set to null. More details are discussed [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/6213). As you've mentioned, this issue should be fixed as of version 1.3.0.

To fetch the display name configured during Registration, you can fetch by calling `currentUser` on your FirebaseAuth instance.

```dart
var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
debugPrint('${currentUser.displayName}');
```

Comment: Hey @Omatt, I am still having getting null after upgrading to 1.3.0. any code how can I set the displayName ?

Comment: Could you check if `displayName` gets successfully updated? You can update the displayName using `userCredential.user.updateDisplayName('Mohamed Rahuman').then(() => debugPrint('${userCredential.user.displayName}')).onError((error) => debugPrint('$error'));`

Comment: Still getting "null".. did you try it ?

Comment: Turns out that fetching displayName during UserCredential registration still gets null. Try fetching `displayName` using `currentUser`. I've tried and it worked for me.

Comment: ok I will try try to read from currentUser.

Comment: Hey Omatt.. reading from current user works, but need to signOut when creating new user, when sign back in it will display the displayName. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who needs to see this but in my case I wanted the `displayName` from the users Google/Apple/Facebook account, so I needed to use the values from `providerData` instead.

```js
user.providerData[0].displayName
```